# Finding the basis of a product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $T = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, X\}$, $Y = \{4, 5\}$, and $U = \{\varnothing, \{4\}, Y\}$. How do I find the basis $B$ for the product topology on $X \times Y$?

Definition: A topological space $(X, T)$ is a Hausdorff space provided
that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct members of $X$ then there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \in V$.

With this definition, how do I solve this question?

Comment: What have you tried? Add more information so that people can know how to guide you

Comment: The definition is not really relevant to the question you ask. A more relevant thing to put would be the definition of product topology that you aware of.

Comment: Do you see any relevance between the definition of a Hausdorff space and the question you need to answer?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I don't really see any relevance in this definition with regards to the question. That's why asked for expert help.

Comment: The definition does not come in anywhere around here. You should check the definition of product topology and you will get your answer easily without using any help.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn thanks for the recommendation and your input really helped

Comment: @SalamMendy Please consider accepting the answer so the question is filed as "answered" on the site.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn done.

Comment: How can you ask question like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's recall the definition of the product topology. The product topology of $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(Y,\tau_2)$ is the topology $\tau_3$ defined on $X\times Y$ that **by definition** has as a basis the collection $\{U\times V: U\in\tau_1, V\in\tau_2\}$.

So the basis here is $$\bigg{\{}\emptyset, \{(1,4)\}, \{(1,4),(1,5)\}, \{(1,4),(2,4)\}, \{(1,4),(2,4),(1,5),(2,5)\}, \{(1,4),(2,4),(3,4)\}, X\times Y\bigg{\}}$$